# how to organize constraints

Tags: swift, constraints

I'm trying to organize my view to maximize labels with numbers in all device position.

Here is project with view: https://github.com/llodi/View

In vertical position it looks good, in horizontal isn't

[image: vertical]

[image: horizontal]

I had tried to use Stack View It didn't help me. Could you give me some advice?

Also I had tried to play with hugging priority and resistance priority but it did not help me also

Comment: Have you looked into [Size Classes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) yet?

Comment: Thanx. I use it but only for constraints. 
I've tried to use it for font size. Now It looks better, but string labels are not fully sized. of course I can use smaller fonts but It wont be good for all devices